# how does main view recognises which editor template is to be included

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help with editor template in mvc3.
I want to know that how does the view comes to know that which editor template is to be called in `EditorFor`? Is any type of reference ios added somewhere?
For eg. - i am having 2 editor templates called `template1.cshtml` and `template2.cshtml` and i m writting the following statement - 
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.template)`
(template is the list of model named `Template`)
Now how `EditorFor` will recognise that `template1` is to be included or `template2`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now how EditorFor will recognise that template1 is to be included or template2? Thanks.

If the template property is `IEnumerable<Template>` then it will include `Template.cshtml`.

So here's the general rule:

If the property you are using in the EditorFor call is not a collection (`IEnumerable<T>`) then ASP.NET MVC will look for a template which has the same name as the type of the property. For example:

```
public MyViewModel FooBar { get; set; }
```

will look for `MyViewModel.cshtml`. You could override this behavior using the `UIHint` attribute. Thus:

```
[UIHint("Baz")]
public MyViewModel FooBar { get; set; }
```

will look for `Baz.cshtml`.

If the property is a collection (`IEnumerable<T>`) then ASP.NET MVC will look for an editor template that has the same name as the type of the elements of your collection.

Thus:

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> Foos { get; set; }
```

will use `MyViewModel.cshtml` which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection.

If on the other hand you used `UIHint`:

```
[UIHint("Bar")]
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> Foos { get; set; }
```

then `Bar.cshtml` will be rendered but there's a catch: it won't be rendered for each element of the collection but it will directly be passed the collection as model and you will have to loop inside. This is by design.

As far as the location of the template is concerned, ASP.NET MVC will first look in a subfolder called EditorTemplates for the current controller and then in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. This allows you to override some global templates for the current controller.

Alternatively you could specify the name of the template to be rendered when using the EditorFor helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyProperty, "Bar")
```

will use `Bar.cshtml`. Same rule applies for collections as with the `UIHint`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Darin. I am clear on the point now. Thanks.